# A Question About Vector Fields, GTM 218

Tags: general-topology, geometry, manifolds, vector-fields

I'm reading John Lee's *smooth manifolds*. I have a simple question about the Proposition $8.16$. Sorry about the long text which is necessary to explain my question.

Here is the statement of the proposition and its proof.

[image]

---

In the statement, he says that "*for every smooth real-valued function $f$ defined on $\color{red}{an}$ open subset*". Let's denote this set(i.e. $dom(f)\,$) by $D$.

I think for this set $D$, we must have that $F(M)\subseteq D$. But I am not sure if my thought is right. **So my question is**, does $D$ must satisfy that $F(M)\subseteq D$?

**My reasoning:** If $F(M)\not\subseteq D$, then $\exists \,p$ s.t. $F(p)\notin D$. Hence, there exists an small neighborhood of $F(p)$ in which $f$ is not defined. Then the expression $dF_p (X_p)f$ makes no sense because $dF_p (X_p)\in T_{F(p)} N$ and $f$ is not defined in a neighborhood of $F(p)$.

I am really confused now and I've been thinking of this for an hour. Thanks for help.

Comment: If you read the first part of his proof, Lee says "For any $p\in M$ and any smooth real-valued $f$ defined in a neighborhood of $F(p)$". Implicitly, he's glossing over this fact. It's a little too pedantic but $F(p)\in U$ for some open $U\subset N$ such that $f\in C^\infty(U)$. In particular, this works everywhere where it makes sense to work (where it is well-defined).

Comment: Maybe it's too pedantic but I just want to make things rigorous. I think we may still need the stronger condition that $F(M)\subseteq D$. Because in the equation (8.6), he writes that $X(f\circ F)=(Yf)\circ F$ which means $X(f\circ F)(p)=(Yf)\circ F (p)$ for all $p\in M$. Since $(Yf)\circ F (p)=Y_{F(p)} f$, we need $F(p)$ lies in the domain of $f$. Since $p$ is arbitrary, we conclude that $F(M)\subseteq D$.

Comment: Ah I see, I completely forgot the statement should work for all $p\in M$. Then I think you're right, any $f$ has to be defined at least on the image of $F$.

Comment: @Ken Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: Really quick aside that I just thought about. In the proof he chooses arbitrary $p$ and says let $f$ be defined on a neighborhood of $F(p)$. Since $p$ is arbitrary, this should work for all $p$. In particular, $F(M)\subset D$ since we're defined in a neighborhood of every $F(p)$.